# How to navigate to home screen after successfully login in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

[image]

I'm using the following code for login. But the problem is after successfully login it's not able to navigate to home page. If I navigate inside on pressed button then it automatically navigate to home and it will not check either user exists or not.

```
try {
  final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailAddress,
    password: password
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
}
```

I have called isUserLoggedIn function after pressing login button.

Comment: Look up and use Provider package. A basic package for state management in Flutter. Should be one of the first you learn about with Flutter. https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check for the user and navigate based on that, HoRiz has answered.

But I would suggest that you implement a state management solution first like `BLoC, Riverpod, etc`. It will help you to manage all your data like **user info** or any other data.

Also if you are not using named routes, then you can use this instead to navigate:

```js
Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => NewScreen(),
                ),
              );
```

Also, if want to learn all the things about routing then you can check Flutter's Oficial Website: [Link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Change like this,

```
try {
  final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailAddress,
    password: password
  );
  //---------------------- add this part --------------
 if (user != null) {
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    '/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  // route set to use this. 
}
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
}
```

---

You can also use this method,

```
Navigator.push(
    context, 
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => HomePage(),
    ),
  );
```

But If you use this, the user can back to login screen without `signout`. So, use `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` method to navigate. It will remove all past routes. can't go back.

Read about [pushNamedAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html)

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomePage()));

Answer (score 0):

I am learning flutter and was stumbled with same problem. Sharing my knowledge here:

To navigate to any screen, you have to use Navigator. In OP's code, navigator code was missing. Navigation can be done using named routes(a clean approach) or directly using the routes.

To use named routes, create a file app_routes.dart

```
class AppRoutes {
  static const String login = '/login';
  static const String home = '/';
  static const String explore = '/explore';
}
```

And you can navigate to any screen using:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.home);
```

Now, there are 2 issues here:

1. Using the pushNamed method will simply push the user to another screen and the user will be able to come back to original screen. So, we have to use **pushReplacementNamed** method which will replace the previous screen(Login screen) with our new screen(Home screen).
   So, instead of using pushNamed, use pushReplacementNamed

   Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, AppRoutes.home);

On Home screen, you can set appBar's automaticallyImplyLeading property to false to hide the back button from the app bar

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Sample'),
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  ),
```

2. Using context inside an async function is not recommended. The lint will show this warning:

**Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps.**

What happens is when you are awaiting for something, the current widget might be removed from the widget tree causing an error when using context. So we have to put a safety check to see if the current widget is still active in the widget tree or not.

In Flutter, the mounted property is a boolean value that indicates whether the widget is currently in the widget tree or not. It is true when the widget is active and part of the widget tree and false when the widget has been removed from the widget tree.

It is a good practice to prevent any state updates or navigation actions if the widget is no longer in the widget tree. This is important to avoid potential errors or issues that might occur if the widget has been removed while an async operation (such as the login API call) is still in progress.

So, before using context in an async function, put a safety check:

```
if (!mounted) return;
```